# What's wrong with my STFT implementation?

Tags: matlab, fft, audio, convolution, stft

I'm studying the linear convolution for achieve more complex results in Audio FX.

My main goal is to implement a realtime convolution between two stream of sound in live perfomance (for example Sound 1 from a synthesizer and Sound2 from a guitar o microphone) .

The length of sounds are not determinate and for testing i recorded two part of these streams. You can think the file used in Matlab as a part of infinite streams.

I have two audio files (`x1` and `x2`) with same fixed length (len1 and len2 = 673792 samples) and from DSP theory i know that the length of convolution array is `lenOut = (len1+len2-1)`.

You can download the input audio files at these links

http://www.sun-art.org/download/matlab/test_01.aif

http://www.sun-art.org/download/matlab/test_02.aif

I wrote two OCTAVE  procedures

1. with direct convolution using `conv(n,m)` function
2. with FFT product of input signals with zero padding

Both procedures gives the same results.
You can download the output  audio files (30 seconds long each) at these links:

http://www.sun-art.org/download/matlab/conv.wav

http://www.sun-art.org/download/matlab/convFFT.wav

The next step is to make a realtime convolution using STFT but before going in C++ i would like to improve it and test it in Matlab/Octave. 
(my reference are: *"SPECTRAL AUDIO SIGNAL PROCESSING"*  by Julius O. Smith III   and  *"DAFX: Digital Audio Effects"* by Udo Zölzer).

I noticed that the result of STFT procedure is quite different from direnct convolution/FFT product procedure.
You can download the output file at this link http://www.sun-art.org/download/matlab/STFTAudioConv.wav

The file is 30 seconds long, but from 15 seconds onwards the audio is zero.
It'possible to achieve the result of function Matlab conv() with STFT procedure ?
  What's wrong with my STFT ?

Below you will find the three procedures.

1) LINEAR CONVOLUTION

```
    [x1, FS] = audioread('conv_test\test_01.aif');
    [x2, FS] = audioread('conv_test\test_02.aif');

    y        = conv(x1,x2);
    outFile  = y / max(abs(y));

    audiowrite ('conv_test\conv.wav', outFile, FS );  %Octave
```

2) FFT PRODUCT

```
    % ============= LOAD audio files x1 and x2==============
    [x1, FS] = audioread('conv_test\test_01.aif');
    [x2, FS] = audioread('conv_test\test_02.aif');

    % x1 and x2 are files with the same length / length(x1) = length(x2) = 673792 samples
    len1   = length(x1);
    len2   = length(x2);  
    lenOut = len1 + len2 - 1;

    N      = 2^nextpow2(lenOut);   %for FFT and padding

    % ============= PADDING _ & scaling =============
    inx1   = [x1;  zeros(N-len1,1)] / max( abs(x1) );
    inx2   = [x2;  zeros(N-len2,1)] / max( abs(x2) );

    %============= FFT of signal x1 =============

    f1     = fft(inx1); 
    r1     = abs(f1);
    phi1   = angle(f1);
    fft1   = (r1.* exp(i*phi1));

    %============= FFT of signal x2 =============

    f2     = fft(inx2);
    r2     = abs(f2);
    phi2   = angle(f2);
    fft2   = (r2.* exp(i*phi2));

    %============= FFT PRODUCT  and iFFT =============

    Yfft   = fft1 .* fft2;
    yout   = real( ifft(Yfft) );

    %============= Write and Save iFFT (linear convolution) =============

    outFile = yout(1:lenOut) / max( abs(yout) );
    audiowrite ('conv_test\convFFT.wav', outFile, FS);  %Octave
```

3) STFT

For Overlapp-Add i define an Hanning window with L = 1024 samples, an Hopsize of L/2 = 512 samples 
and an FFT size `N = 2^nextpow2(L+1) = 2048` samples.
In the while loop

1. take 1024 (L) samples of inputs with windowing
2. zero padding with (N-L) = 1024 zeros. The buffer length in the FFT is now 2048 samples long.
3. FFT of zero padded inputs
4. FFT product
5. iFFT
6. overlapp add the output
7. HopSize advance

Fixing the windows lenght L = 1024 implicitly I also fixed the signal (x1) and filter (x2) size L  and FFT size = 2*L .

My inpulse response (x2) as the other signal is varying-time. My processor has two input buffer (left and right channel) for example 16 samples long. I collect L = 1024 sample in new two auxilaty buffers (in1 and in2 in Script 3) and after windowing i extend them with zero-pad until the FFT size ( = 2*L)

```
    % ============= LOAD audio files x1 and x2==============
    [x1, FS] = audioread('conv_test\test_01.aif');
    [x2, FS] = audioread('conv_test\test_02.aif');

    % x1 and x2 are files with the same length / length(x1) = length(x2) = 673792 samples
    len1     = length(x1);
    len2     = length(x2);  
    lenOut   = len1 + len2 - 1;

    L         = 1024;               % length of analisys windows
    w1        = hanningz(L);        % w = .5*(1 - cos(2*pi*(0:L-1)'/(L)));
    hop       = L/2;
    N         = 2^nextpow2(L+1);    % FFT length

    out       = zeros(lenOut,1);    %init of output
    start     = 0;                  %index of while loop
    pout      = 0;
    pend      = (length(x1) - L);   %end of while loop

    % ================== OVERLAPP ADD ==================

    while start<pend

      in1    = x1(start+1:start+L) .* w1;       %windowing
      in2    = x2(start+1:start+L) .* w1;

      max1   = max(abs(in1));
      max2   = max(abs(in2));

      buf1   = [in1; zeros(N-L,1)] / max1;  % zero padding
      buf2   = [in2; zeros(N-L,1)] / max2;

      f1     = fft(buf1);                   % FFT input 1
      r1     = abs(f1);                     
      phi1   = angle(f1);
      ft1    = (r1.* exp(i*phi1));

      f2     = fft(buf2);                   % FFT input 2
      r2     = abs(f2);
      phi2   = angle(f2);
      ft2    = (r2.* exp(i*phi2));  

      YConv  = ft1 .* ft2;                  % Convolution - FFT Product

      y      = real( ifft(YConv) );         % iFFT

      out(pout+1:pout+N) = out(pout+1:pout+N) + y;  % Overlapp-Ddd

      start  = start + hop;
      pout   = pout + hop;

    end

    % ================== Write and Save ==================

    out = out / max(abs(out));        
    audiowrite ('conv_test\STFTAudioConv.wav', out, FS ); %Octave
```

Comment: You are mixing up STFT and Overlap-Add. STFT is used to visualize Amplitude v/s Frequency v/s Time. It is different from obtaining convolution of 2 signals using Overlap-Add. You are splitting second sequence also. That is not correct. Overlap - Add is used when one sequence is large length and another small length. You do not split second sequence. But here both seems to be having large lengths.

Comment: @jithin you can certainly also split the second sequence, if the impulse response is very long. That's a very common thing to do with things like room impulse responses. It's typically called a block convolver.

Comment: Thanks @Hilmar. Never heard of it before. Will explore.

Comment: I would suggest that the question is re-phrased to something a bit more specific. Perhaps it could become about clarifying the methods at a higher level? This will make you see if something you are doing in your code should be modified.

Comment: @A_A read the second Answers :)

Comment: @Hilmar  read the second Answers :)

Comment: Thanks for letting us know about this. Can you please delete your "answer" and post it as an "edit" to your main question? SE is not a "forum" per se. We can have a dialogue through comments but the main purpose is Q&A. This is the reason for asking the question to be clear and succint, so that it receives useful answers, rather than sparking dialogue. If you are trying to clarify some things in your mind, you might want to try the DSP chat too (?).

Comment: @A_A is there a chat ?  i'm new user on DSP .stackExchange

Comment: There is one, [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=dsp.stackexchange.com). All communities have one I think. You may not get a response immediately, but it is the better place if you are not sure about the topic of your question.

Comment: BTW, another common name for "block convolution" is "fast convolution". You'll find plenty of info...

Comment: @NigelRedmon: I don't think that's correct. "Fast convolution" of often used for Overlap Add. What I'm talking  about is an extension to Overlap-add (or overlap save) that also segments the impulse response as well.

Comment: @Hilmar I think the question was expanded since I read...I was replying to "I'm studying the linear convolution...My main goal is to implement a realtime convolution". I suppose that you're saying that "fast convolution" is not another name for "block convolution"? I'm not saying they are synonymous, but block convolution is an implementation of fast convolution, no? The point is you can search for either and come to the same place, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

A few points

1. It is very unusual to convolve two audio files. You typically convolve one audio file with the impulse response of a filter. Thinking about "long file" and "short-ish" impulse response makes it easier to understand
2. For overlap add the FFT size is determined by the length of the filter. For example, if your file length is 670k samples and your impulse response is 16k samples, you would chose an FFT size of twice the short one, i.e. 32k. You multiply the FFT of each input frame with the FFT of the entire filter.
3. You don't window. Or to be precise: you use a rectangular window.
4. If your impulse response is too long for a single FFT (for latency, memory or CPU reasonse), you can chop this up as well, but that's more complicated and you should not do this until you have Overall Add figured out.
5. Overlap add is NOT the same as STFT. (see jithin's comment)
6. Your code has a lot of unnecessary stuff in it. You extract amplitude and phase from the FFT of the block and put them together again. Why? $ft1 = f1$
7. You normalize the input to the maxium of a windowed frame. That's just plain wrong

**Update based on added info**

> My main goal is to implement a realime convolution between two stream of sound in live perfomance(for example sound 1 from a synthesizer and sound2 from a guitar o microphone) So the length of sounds are non determinate. For testing i recorded two part of these streams. You can think the file used in Matlab as a part of infinite streams.

Sorry, that won't work. You can't convolve two infinite sequences with a finite amount of latency. In essence one of the sequences must be time reversed, and you can't reverse an infinite sequence without waiting infinitely long.